# Evaluate the smoothness of a parametric unknown nonlinear function

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, smooth-functions

I have a (black-box) function $f(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{\theta})$ which depends on $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,...,x_N)$ a set of RGB images and a set of *real* and *discrete* parameters $\mathbf{\theta}$.

I cannot evaluate the derivative directly, but I can evaluate in 30 minutes $f$ at a point by fixing $\mathbf{\theta}$, thus, evaluating a lot of derivatives by finite difference is prohibitively expensive.

$f$ is an entire algorithm with stochastic methods inside.

**Q:**

- I would like to know if $f$ is smooth in its **parameters** $\mathbf{\theta}$ for any $\mathbf{x}$.
- If it is not smooth, I would like to know if it is smooth in some parameters $\theta_i$ ?
- Are there local propreties I can exploit to know if it is smooth everywhere?
- Do you have some nice references on this problem so I can dig deeper?
- Ideally, I would like to know if it is smooth for any parameters $\mathbf{\theta}$ **and** any input $\mathbf{x}$ in the future by exploiting the fact that $\mathbf{x}$ is a set of RGB images.

I'm particularly interested in the analysis of the local properties of the function or in algorithmic approaches to prove almost certainly that the function is smooth.

Thanks :)

Comment: Without knowing more about $f$, there is no way we can answer any of your questions.

Comment: $f$ is an entire (big) algorithm using probabilistic methods inside. I don't know if that helps.. but in any case, I cannot find an analytical form of $f$ or at least I don't know how to transform an entire software in a (set of) mathematical expression.

Comment: Try to put yourself in my position. I tell you I have a function, $G$. Oh, and $G$ is hard to compute. Can you tell me now if $G$ is smooth?

Comment: Yes I understand the point, but I don't even know how to express the function. I was looking for probabilistic or locality properties that I can exploit to proove that my function is smooth in the parameters. It can be a mathematical theorem on smooth manifolds or a probabilistic approach to sample my function in a meaningful way.